# Mocking private enum inside tested class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermock

I'm using PowerMock/EasyMock and want to test a class which has a private enum, like this:

```
public class GenerateMove {

  private Command current;
  private enum Command {
    GO, BACK, TURN
  }


  public move() {
    if (Command.GO.equals(current)) {
     // do something
    }
  }

}
```

I am unable to mock the Command enum. Is there away to do so? Otherwise how can I test the `// do something` code inside `move()` method?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not have the `Command` enum an "outer" enum and have it generate `GenerateMove` instances? enums can have methods etc...

Answer (score 3):

Typically, private fields relate to internal functions, or the internal state of the class - essentially, it is the stuff that you're going to to test.

By passing in `command`, you indicate that you can change the state of the object, and you need to verify all possible states that can be passed through.  However, by having that enumeration `private`, you *can't* pass it through since it's not in any other package scope.

If you don't want this enumeration to be exposed *too* far, you can change its scope to package-private (by removing `private`), and have your test method in the same classpath.  This way, your test method will be able to use the enumeration, and you'll be able to verify your results with respect to what you pass to it.

There isn't any reason to mock that - you should pass real data instead and test all cases of that enumeration to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need of mocking an enum. You can use the enum members directly. 
To test your move method ,it's all about what code you have. Mocking will help you if you have any external dependent class object.